# Problemas para validar un XML con un XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Tengo problemas para validar un documento XML con un Schema XSD.

El error que me da es el siguiente. Tengo otro documento para validar en el que me sale el mismo error. No entiendo que me falta.

> Error at line 19, column 25: content of element declaration must match
>   (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Videoteca data_creación="24/02/2009" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="peliculas.xsd">>
    <Película id="1">
            <Título>El santo</Título>
            <TítuloOrixinal>The Saint</TítuloOrixinal>
            <Ano>1997</Ano>
            <Director>Phillip Noyce</Director>
            <Xénero>Acción</Xénero>
            <Duración>111</Duración>
            <Actor principal="SI" sexo="home">
                    <Nome>Val Kilmer</Nome>
                    <DataNacemento>31/12/1959</DataNacemento>
            </Actor>
            <!-- Elisabeth Shue -->
            <Actor principal="NO" id="51"/>
    </Película>
    <Película id="2">
            <Título>¿Teléfono rojo? Volamos hacia Moscú</Título>
            <TítuloOrixinal>Dr. Strangelove, or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</TítuloOrixinal>
            <Ano>1963</Ano>
            <Director>Stanley Kubrick</Director>
            <Duración>90</Duración>
            <Actor principal="SI" sexo="home">
                    <Nome>Peter Sellers</Nome>
            </Actor>
    </Película>
    <Película id="3">
            <Título>Leaving Las Vegas</Título>
            <TítuloOrixinal>Leaving Las Vegas</TítuloOrixinal>
            <Ano>1995</Ano>
            <Director>Mike Figgis</Director>
            <Xénero>Drama</Xénero>
            <Duración>107</Duración>
            <Actor principal="SI" sexo="home">
                    <Nome>Nicolas Cage</Nome>
                    <DataNacemento>7/01/1964</DataNacemento>
            </Actor>
            <!-- Elisabeth Shue -->
            <Actor id="51" principal="SI"/>
            <Actor sexo="home">
                    <Nome>Julian Sands</Nome>
            </Actor>
    </Película>
    <Película id="4">
            <Título>¿A quién ama Gilbert Grape?</Título>
            <TítuloOrixinal>What's Eating Gilbert Grape?</TítuloOrixinal>
            <Ano>1993</Ano>
            <Director>Lasse Hallström</Director>
            <Xénero>Drama</Xénero>
            <Duración>118</Duración>
            <!-- Johnny Depp -->
            <Actor id="139" principal="SI"/>
            <Actor sexo="muller">
                    <Nome>Juliette Lewis</Nome>
            </Actor>
    </Película>
</Videoteca>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Videoteca">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Pelicula" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Tïtulo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="TïtuloOrixinal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Ano" type="xs:NMTOKEN" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Director" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Xénero" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Duración" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="data_creación" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required"/>
          <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Actor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Nome" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="DataNacemento" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="principal" type="xs:string" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:enumeration value="SI"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="NO"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          <xs:attribute name="sexo" type="xs:string" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:enumeration value="home"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="muller"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: ¿Son dos documentos distintos o ambos en un mismo documento? Si quieres ayuda pon el documento XML tal cual estás intentando validarlo. En la pregunta no se entiende bien si están juntos o separados. ¿O es el XSD (el 2º código que has puesto) el que está dando problemas?

Comment: Son dos documentos distintos. Está puesto tal cual lo estoy intentando validar

Comment: He verificado los dos documentos que has puesto en [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) y **ninguno de los dos arroja error**, arrojan ambos dos warning, pero el validator indica que los documentos son correctos: **This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!** O sea, dicen que los documentos están bien formados. Si quieres pruébalo tu mismo.

Comment: Si, dice que está bien formado pero lo que necesito ahora es validarlo y es ahí donde me da el error.

Comment: Como te he dicho, **no hay error** en los documentos según el validator. El warning dice que no tiene indicado el DOCTYPE, pero eso no significa que sea erróneo, es una advertencia. El enlace que te puse es el mejor validator de XML que existe y si dice que no hay error, no lo hay, a no ser que hayas compartido en la pregunta el archivo que no es. El resultado de la validación dice que **este documento fue verificado con éxito y es un XML bien formado!** si tuviese error lo habría indicado.

Comment: Si lo se, yo también lo comprobé y me dice que está bien formado y el XML Copy Editor que es el programa que uso, también me dice que lo está, pero aparte de estar bien formado tiene que estar validado, que es diferente. El schema XSD tiene que estar validado, no me sirve solo que esten bien formados los dos documentos

Comment: Encontré una página de validación de documentos y me saca el mismo error que pongo en el problema
http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: Ya vi, el problema que tienes es que en tu XSD hay varios tags abiertos sin cerrar. Mira un esquema completo: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp cuando abres un `complexType`, una `sequence`, un `element` o cualquier otra cosa, debes cerrarla luego. Revisa eso.

Comment: No, están todas bien cerradas, sino entonces tampoco me diria que los documentos están bien formados

Answer (score 2):

Es un problema de formación de los elementos, los cuales deben corresponder en el XML y en XSD tanto en los nombres como en la estructura de los datos.

Hay errores de no coincidencia de etiquetas, por ejemplo `Título` no es lo mismo que `Tïtulo`:

**XML**

```
<Título>El santo</Título>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:element name="Tïtulo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Luego, los diferentes elementos **Película** del XML no parecen estar estructurados de la misma forma. Una película habría de ser como una entidad y todas las películas deberían tener **la misma estructura de datos**: Autor, Fecha, Titulo, etc. Tampoco debería haber ids repetidos, que era uno de los errores que me daba al intentar validar el documento.

También **yo evitaría el uso de tildes o acentos en los nombres de las etiquetas y de los elementos.**.

Este sería un ejemplo sencillo.

Fíjate como en el XML cada elemento `book`, o sea, `bk001` y `bk002` tienen **la misma estructura de datos**:

```
 id,author,title,genre,price,review
```

Luego, fíjate que en el XSD, en el  `complexType name="BookForm` tenemos esta misma estructura, es decir: `id,author,title,genre,price,review` escritos de la misma manera:

```
<xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
      <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

---

**Dos archivos de ejemplo completos**
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x:books xmlns:x="urn:books">
   <book id="bk001">
      <author>Writer</author>
      <title>The First Book</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <review>An amazing story of nothing.</review>
   </book>

   <book id="bk002">
      <author>Poet</author>
      <title>The Poet's First Poem</title>
      <genre>Poem</genre>
      <price>24.95</price>
      <review>Least poetic poems.</review>
   </book>
</x:books>
```

**XSD**

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="urn:books"
            xmlns:bks="urn:books">

  <xsd:element name="books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="book" 
                  type="bks:BookForm" 
                  minOccurs="0" 
                  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
      <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya di con el problema, el Actor tenía que ir en el complextype de Pelicula y no en un complextype aparte como yo lo tenía. Ahora si bien formado y validado. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Marca como solución la respuesta si te ha ayudado a resolver el problema, o bien elimina la pregunta. Saludos.